# Accessing child class prototype from parent class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to implement a base class method, that have the same logic for all child classes, but would use some of their variables, that are specific to them.

```
function A() {}
A.prototype.foo = 'bar';
A.prototype.getFoo = function () {
    console.log('Called class: ' + this.constructor.name);
    return this.foo;
};

function B() {}
B.prototype.foo = 'qaz';
require('util').inherits(B, A);

console.log(B.prototype.getFoo());
```

The last line prints `bar`, but getFoo() also prints `Called class: B`. So I'm wondering, since I can access the child's constructor, is there a way to access child's prototype through it?

Comment: Only put functions on the prototype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`require('util').inherits` resets `B.prototype` to a new object that inherits `A`.
Any properties you set on the old prototype are lost.

If you set `B.prototype.foo` *after* calling `inherits()`, it will work fine.